LLVM DAG Pattern Instruction Selection Fails after introducing a new intrinsic
I am currently expanding a RISC-V core with a custom load instruction. For this question, the specifics are unimportant. It functionally behaves like a normal load instruction and should use the same RISC-V instruction format just with a different opcode.
I implemented an intrinsic to give the programmer the ability to emit this specific instruction:
uint16_t x = __builtin_riscv_customload16(pointer_here);
In the SelectionDAG I handled the intrinsic call as follows:
case Intrinsic::customload16: {
    SDValue Ops[2];
    SDValue Root = getRoot();
    Ops[0] = getValue(I.getArgOperand(0));
    MachineSDNode* Op = DAG.getMachineNode(TargetOpcode::H_LOAD16, sdl, Ops[0].getValueType(), Ops[0]);
    SDValue Op_new1 = SDValue(Op, 0);
    setValue(&I, Op_new1);
    DAG.setRoot(Root);
    return;
  }

This works fine for small functions with optimisations or larger functions without optimisations. I now tried my intrinsic on a larger function which does a lot of binary operations. It works fine with -O0 but with -O3, LLVM crashes.
LLVM crashes during the instruction selection while visiting an XOR node. It probably tries to optimise it in some way or fold some instructions together. It crashes in the "llvm::SelectionDAG::getNode()" function, where:
  case ISD::OR:
  case ISD::XOR:
  case ISD::ADD:
  case ISD::SUB:
    assert(VT.isInteger() && "This operator does not apply to FP types!");
    assert(N1.getValueType() == N2.getValueType() &&
           N1.getValueType() == VT && "Binary operator types must match!");
    // (X ^|+- 0) -> X.  This commonly occurs when legalizing i64 values, so
    // it's worth handling here.
    if (N2CV && N2CV->isZero())
      return N1;

It triggers the second assertion as N1 has type i16 and N2 has type i32. The crash happens at the return N1; statement.
I am confused how to handle this as I thought LLVM will automatically handle the integer promotion.
The call stack looks like follows:
#10 0x000055d8479f4566 llvm::SelectionDAG::getNode(unsigned int, llvm::SDLoc const&, llvm::EVT, llvm::SDValue, llvm::SDValue, llvm::SDNodeFlags) /home/hidev/llvm-project/llvm/lib/CodeGen/SelectionDAG/SelectionDAG.cpp:6427:14
#11 0x000055d847969902 llvm::SelectionDAGBuilder::visitBinary(llvm::User const&, unsigned int) /home/hidev/llvm-project/llvm/lib/CodeGen/SelectionDAG/SelectionDAGBuilder.cpp:3266:37
#12 0x000055d8479acc46 llvm::SelectionDAGBuilder::visitXor(llvm::User const&) /home/hidev/llvm-project/llvm/lib/CodeGen/SelectionDAG/SelectionDAGBuilder.h:567:61
#13 0x000055d84795c626 llvm::SelectionDAGBuilder::visit(unsigned int, llvm::User const&) /home/hidev/llvm-project/llvm/include/llvm/IR/Instruction.def:166:1

Does anybody have any hint how to solve this problem?
To solve the problem I tried reading into the Documentation, but I am confused what is actually going on as I thought LLVM will automatically promote integers to larger types.
I am using LLVM 17!

When asking questions about SelectionDAG, it is better to post related fragment of it. Run compiler in the debugger and print DAG of the basic block via BB->dump() method.

Indeed, LLVM is able to promote integer types, but it will happen only during LegalizeTypes pass on SelectionDAG. If your MachineNode is build too late, that Legalizer won't fix it.
